# Using OpenStreetMapX to create a powergrid graph network

Tags: julia, openstreetmap, lightgraphs

I want to find out a few things about OpenStreetMapX which from what I understand works well with transportation-based networks. I am wondering if it's also possible to use this package along with `lightgraphs.jl` to create a power grid network. In my case, I have filtered some power grid data using osmosis (a piece of software that allows filtering OpenStreetMap data based on a tag)

I want to know whether it is relevant to use OpenStreetMapX for this kind of data (power grid)?

```
 using OpenStreetMapX
 # Load power data for Germany
 deData = get_map_data("D:/PowerGridNetwork/data/germany/de_power_160718.osm")
 # Get roadways (which I believe has the meta data for edges)
 deData.roadways
```

[image]

I ended up with metadata for power as well as roads, which I am wondering, how it came in the first place. Since I filtered only the power data.

The next question I have is, does `deData.e` returns an adjacency list?. Since what I am really after is creating a MetaGraph with nodes and edges with their respective properties.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance